# Read function - FileSystemObject

Tags: javascript, activex, filesystemobject

Using ActiveX - FileSystemObject I would like to:
- Open an existing file
- Read the first 28 bytes from it and store them in var str1
- Read the next 1000 bytes from it and store them in var str2
- Create a new file with this content: str1 + text_param + str2

This is my Javascript code:

```
function exportFile(text)
{   
    var fso, f2;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f2 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\default.js",1)
    var str1=f2.Read(28);
    f2.Skip(28);
    var str2=f2.Read(1000);
    f2.Close;
    f2.CreateTextFile("C:\\new.js",true);
    f2.Write(str1+text+str2);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error message (in Spanish), refering to the line of the f2.Close. It says, literally, "The object does not accept this property of method". I tried removing this line and the error goes to the next line (CreateTextFile).

Could you help me? THANKS

```
Detalles de error de página web

Agente de usuario: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Fecha: Sun, 7 Nov 2010 11:37:07 UTC


Mensaje: El objeto no acepta esta propiedad o método
Línea: 69
Carácter: 5
Código: 0
URI: file:///C:/freeEdition.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `()` after `f2.close`.